# How to do python zip() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, translate

I have this function that I'm trying to translate to javascript.

```
def pascal(n):
    row = [1]
    k = [0]
    for x in range(max(n,0)):
        print(row)
        row=[l+r for l,r in zip(row+k,k+row)]
    return n>=1
```

I'm having troubles with `zip`.

I cant figure how to translate that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: underscore.js has a `zip` function. Do you need to write your own?

Comment: Don't get so sidetracked by the `zip` function. You are just trying to print out pascals triangle. Concentrate on this problem and try to find other implementations you could translate to javascript more easily.

Comment: Seconding @PaulRooney - taking good Python code and directly translating it into Javascript isn't necessarily going to produce good Javascript, in the same way that translating best-practice C or C++ into Python doesn't necessarily give best-practice Python, and translating, say, best practice Haskell directly into Python could easily produce very very *bad* Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think emulating `zip` is the best approach here. It's pretty inefficient Python code in the first place, as it spends a lot of time creating those temporary lists just so `zip` can be used

```
function pascal(n) {
    row = [1]
    for (var x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        console.log(row);
        new_row = [1]
        for (var k = 1; k < row.length; k++) {
            new_row.push(row[k-1] + row[k]);
        }
        new_row.push(1);
        row = new_row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of a `zip` function for JavaScript.

It doesn't have any error handling... but it'll take unlimited arrays as arguments, and will return them "zipped" as in Python (in this case, as an array of arrays).

If the arrays aren't all the same length, it will error out.

```
function zip() {
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {
        var item = [];
        for (var j in arguments) {
            item.push(arguments[j][i]);
        }
        out.push(item);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it (printing the results tothe console):

**http://jsfiddle.net/wfmbdn40/**

Answer (score 0):

here is a JavaScript implementation for a python like zip function(generator) you can give multiple arrays of different lengths and it will zip them together

```
function* zip(...arrays) {
    let max_len = 0;
    for(let i of arrays){
        if(i.length>max_len){
            max_len = i.length;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(max_len); i++) {
        let temp_arr = [];
        for(let j of arrays){
            temp_arr.push(j[i]);
        }
        yield temp_arr;
    }
}
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3],
    arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 7];
for (let i of zip(arr1, arr2)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Python's zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) takes a bunch of iterables and connects the nth element to the others. If you has two lists, `a` with `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `n` with `[1, 2, 3]`, the result of `zip(a, n)` would be `['a', 1]`, `['b', 2]`, `['c', 3]`.

Comment: This is accurate but doesn't quite address the question of how to do that in Javascript.

Comment: You're right, but we're not going to write the code for him. I assumed he didn't understand what zip did enough to translate it, so I explained what it did.